# Can you use variables when editing /etc/environment in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, environment-variables

I'm trying to introduce a variable and add it to the global path in ubuntu 10.04.  According to the [official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), /etc/environment is the right place.  Here's what my example looks like:

```
GRADLE_HOME=/etc/gradle-0.9-preview-3
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
```

The GRADLE_HOME variable is added to the environment, but it's not interpreting the $GRADLE_HOME variable during the PATH assignment.  Hard-coding it works fine.  Not a big deal, but I'd like to know if variable substitution is supported, or if there's a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This explanation from a related post appears to provide the answer:

> Because /etc/environment is not a
>   shell script. It is the shell that 
>   does expansion of environment
>   variables. The PAM module pam_env is
>   what  reads /etc/environment - and it
>   treats it as a simple list of KEY=VAL 
>   pairs and sets up the environment
>   accordingly. It has no language for 
>   doing variable expansion.

Comment: so, in short, just use /etc/profile :)

Comment: No, it just means variable substitution doesn't work when editing the global profile.  /etc/profile is a per-user environment location.  sometimes you really do want to edit the global environment settings.

Comment: /etc/profile is per-user...? A per-user file in /etc? Last time I checked /etc/profile is the system-wide ~/.profile. ~/.profile is the per-user location.

Comment: Sorry - misread your comment.  I think /etc/profile is just for interactive shells, and I needed to handle non-interactive shells as well.

Answer (score 1):

Read the pam_env.conf(5) manpage.

I believe you need to add curly-braces around the variable name on the right-hand side:

```
GRADLE_HOME=/etc/gradle-0.9-preview-3
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:${GRADLE_HOME}/bin"
```

> (Possibly non-existent) environment
>   variables may be used in values using
>   the ${string} syntax and (possibly
>   non-existent) PAM_ITEMs may be used in
>   values using the @{string} syntax.
>   Both the $ and @ characters can be
>   backslash escaped to be used as
>   literal values values can be delimited
>   with "", escaped " not supported. Note
>   that many environment variables that
>   you would like to use may not be set
>   by the time the module is called. For
>   example, HOME is used below several
>   times, but many PAM applications don´t
>   make it available by the time you need
>   it.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work in my environment (10.04 32-bit server). Same effect, where it seems to treat the value as a literal.

Comment: I also tried this and it did not work.